# Retain author after a cherry-pick conflict

Tags: git, commit

after a conflict i get the message to use git commit -c xxxxxx. When i do that i get another window having the desciption of my commit +a author  but have no idea how to move on from there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps you want the `-C` option to `git commit` instead of `-c`. If you're trying to go the other direction, look at `--reset-author`. Either way, have a look at the Options section of `git help commit` to see exactly what each of these does.